# Difference between backslash and minus on domain, range

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

When declaring domain or range, is "$R\setminus\{0\}$" any different than "$R-\{0\}$"?

Comment: No. $\qquad\qquad$

Comment: No.  But $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$ is preferred by just about everyone who isn't me.  However a *FORWARD* slash such as $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ is an *ENTIRELY* different things  (which is why I don't like  $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$.  But I am in the minority).  Note if you type "\$\setminus\$" you get the backslash so... that tells you it means set minus.  In any event $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}=\mathbb R-\{0\} = \{x\in \mathbb R| x\ne 0\}$.  Same thing.

Comment: Backslash is common for set minus. For all sets, not just ranges.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In principle, no. This is a matter of preference.

In practice, sometimes yes. $A-B$ sometimes denotes $\{a-b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$ when $A$ and $B$ are subset of some set where subtraction is well-defined (e.g. sets of reals).

The rule of thumb is that when in doubt, define your notation explicitly. If you are the reader, ask to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

The notation "$R \setminus {0}$" is  usually used when dealing with sets (TeX command: "\setminus").

But also the minus sign is sometimes used and accepted.

Refer also to:

- [Set Difference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetDifference.html)

Comment: I prefer that $\ddot\smile$. So when we should write *(there are?)* $\Bbb R-\{0\}$?

Comment: @manooooh I prefer $\setminus$ :)